# If already connected to MySQL, could PHP mysql_real_escape_string() ever fail?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

Both `mysql_set_charset()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` return `false` on error according to the documentation. It also states that if a MySQL connection is not established before invoking either, an empty connection will be created. I'm thinking the connection is the only factor which could cause an error.

So, if I have already connected to MySQL in PHP, can I safely call `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` and `mysql_real_escape_string('string')` without error handling them?

Comment: You're asking if the above functions work as described in the documentation then the answer is yes. Use the second param `$link_identifier` if you don't like the notion of PHP making assumptions about which identifier to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer must be simply 'Yes'

What you are actually asking is wether the the function will work according to the documentation or not. You should and can safely assume that it does.

Comment: +1 good answer. you could mention that a best practice is to use PDO with parameterized queries.